# memcached questions on a specific request

Tags: php, memcached

I am trying to customize a video script to add memcached support. I managed to do it on simple queries, but i am not sure how to proceed on such sort of queries:

```
$sql            = "SELECT VID, title, duration, addtime, thumb, thumbs, viewnumber, rate, likes, dislikes, type, hd, premium FROM video" . $sql_add . " ORDER BY viewtime DESC LIMIT " . $config['watched_per_page'];
$rs             = $conn->execute($sql);
$viewed_videos  = $rs->getrows();
$viewed_total   = count($viewed_videos);

$smarty->assign('errors',$errors);
$smarty->assign('messages',$messages);
$smarty->assign('menu', 'home');
$smarty->assign('index', true);
$smarty->assign('viewed_total', $viewed_total);
$smarty->assign('viewed_videos', $viewed_videos);
$smarty->assign('recent_videos', $recent_videos);
$smarty->assign('self_title', $seo['index_title']);
$smarty->assign('self_description', $seo['index_desc']);
$smarty->assign('self_keywords', $seo['index_keywords']);
```

Basically, i would like to cache such queries for a couple minutes, so it doesn't overload the index page when there are tons of people coming.

I am not an expert at all, i just bought a script, and i have been tweaking it a lot , but now i would like to make it easier for the server by caching results a little bit.

I did cache a few requests, but those request returned only one thing, not multi SELECT, and i am not sure how to proceed the proper way.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: serialize your output, and store it in memcached. When request comes in, see if you have cached version available, and deserealize it when outputting.

Comment: I pasted my question and it seems i missed the "hello everyone! ", sorry for that

Comment: Dimi, do you have example of that? I wrote things such as getting cached version when there is only one returned answer from SQL. but i don't know how to proceed when there are so many

Comment: you can use json_encode($request_params) and use it as a key for memcached, and json_encode($output) for value. Alternatively, use query caching option in database itself (usually a bad practice). Store all of your output in a single array by either using fetchAll() option, or iterating through results and appending them to array.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do something. I am not a php programmer in the first place. I just use purchased script, but the authors just don't even offer supports in general.